# du Val singularities in Magma

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, singularity-theory, algebraic-surfaces, magma

Is there any way to decide whether a singularity of a surface embedded in $\mathbb{P}^5(\mathbb{Q})$ is a du Val/rational double point in Magma?
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify that your surface has only rational double points, you can use the command ${\tt HasOnlySimpleSingularities}$.

If you want to check only a specific point, you can use instead ${\tt IsSimpleSurfaceSingularity}$.

See Chapter 116 ("Algebraic Surfaces") of the [Handbook of Magma Functions](https://www.math.uzh.ch/sepp/magma-2.19.8-cr/Handbook.pdf) for more details.